# Laravel Send URL with JSON

Tags: json, laravel

i send url with json with this code

```
return response()->json([
    'code' => '200',
    'message' => 'success',
    "resource" => url()."/packages/calibre/images/products/".$artwork->image
]);
```

but when i try to test the response, it's show the link

```
http:\/\/localhost:8000\/packages\/calibre\/ etc..
```

how to fix it? it's have double slash and backslash (/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine,

```
$artwork->imag = 'img.jpg';

return response()->json([
            'code' => '200',
            'message' => 'success',
            "resource" => url("/packages/calibre/images/products/{$artwork->imag}")
        ]);
```

Response in Postman:

```
{
  "code": "200",
  "message": "success",
  "resource": "http://laravel.dev/packages/calibre/images/products/img.jpg"
}
```

Response in Web browser:

```
{"code":"200","message":"success","resource":"http:\/\/laravel.dev\/packages\/calibre\/images\/products"}
```

If you wish to remove slashes from the encoded URL do this:

```
  return response(json_encode([
       'code' => '200',
       'message' => 'success',
       "resource" => url('/packages/calibre/images/products/')
   ], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))->header('Content-Type', "application/json");
```

Response in web browser

```
{"code":"200","message":"success","resource":"http://verimarked.dev/packages/calibre/images/products"}
```

Comment: it's stil have backslash TT

Comment: yess i test with postman and it's right, but when i open the url with browser it's show like before and i can't get url with http request from mobile

Comment: doing var url =  `response.resource` ; will give you a clean url, where response is `{"code":"200","message":"success","resource":"http:\/\/laravel.dev\/packages\/calibre\/images\/products"}`

Comment: I assume you are making this call from javascript, ajax request, which always returns a response or promise,

Comment: sorry i'm newbie for this, i'm making controller that used as api to mobile, this json used for send image url to mobile, but i dont know how to do with my controller to can send clean url

Comment: Thankyou very much, it's help me so much